# OpenAM /json/authenticate ReST api behaves differently on different servers

Tags: openam

I am calling the OpenAM ***/json/authenticate*** api for a realm. The request details are as below. The issue is on one server the response received contains the tokenId directly and on other it gives the authId with callbacks. Both servers are exactly same with same configuration. Any help in fixing the output to get the tokenId directly would be a great help. There is limited help available on OpenAM. This has given me a couple of sleepless nights.

```
Method: POST 
URL: http://localhost:8080/openam/json/authenticate?realm=/MYREALM
Headers:
 1. Content-Type:application/json 
 2. X-OpenAM-Password:Wsdwe@9900
 3. X-OpenAM-Username:sdf.er@dummy.com
```

Output on one server

```
{
    "tokenId": "AQIC5wM2LY4SfcwB_yB8SZ5JOfJSzlbBCIb0645ky5NrwUY.*AAJTSQACMDMAAlNLADASMjExOTAwMjczNDI5Mjg0Mjc3MgACUzEAAjAy*",
    "successUrl": "/openam/console"
}
```

Output on other server

```
{
    "authId": "eyAidHlwIjogIkpXVCIsGHJhbGciOiAiSFMyNTYiIH0.eyAib3RrIjogImo1Y2gybnFqaGwybGhnZ250cWIzazNkMHFpIiwgInJlYWxtIjogIm89aXRzdXBwb3J0MjQ3ZGF0YXN0b3JlLG91PXNlcnZpY2VzLGRjPW9wZW5hbSxkYz1mb3JnAWEvY2ssZGM9b3JnIiwgInNlc3Npb25JZCI6ICJBUUlDNXdNMkxZNFNmY3h0UUDSFGlielFPYkJuUVUxTTNudUlab3JFdEcxX2liNC4qQUFKVFNRQUNNREVBQWxOTEFCTTRPRGcxTkRRME16STFNRFl3TXpnNE5EUTRBQUpUTVFBQSoiIH0.rWE7A_tjcsyiXpQdAXUsS6OiHi97HhXQEkYwY919ovE",
    "template": "",
    "stage": "IDMDataStore1",
    "header": "Access Your Account",
    "callbacks": [
        {
            "type": "NameCallback",
            "output": [
                {
                    "name": "prompt",
                    "value": "Email ID:"
                }
            ],
            "input": [
                {
                    "name": "IDToken1",
                    "value": "sdf.er@dummy.com"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "PasswordCallback",
            "output": [
                {
                    "name": "prompt",
                    "value": "Password:"
                }
            ],
            "input": [
                {
                    "name": "IDToken2",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "TextOutputCallback",
            "output": [
                {
                    "name": "message",
                    "value": "\n            "
                },
                {
                    "name": "messageType",
                    "value": "0"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

NOTE: I am using **OpenAM 13.0.0**

Comment: Any customization in the auth module xml results in this behaviour. This is highly unstable piece of software.

Comment: Is it possible that you have different versions of the IDMDatastore module deployed on the different servers? It's also a common mistake that people don't add their second server to the existing deployment.

Comment: @PeterMajor we had customized the auth module's login form and that looks like a culprit. Any customization in the login form triggers this behaviour.

Comment: Are you applying the same customization to all the OpenAM servers?

Comment: No. One was customized and the other was not. Probably, that was the reason for the difference in the output.